# QTableWidget - Change the row color

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I'm trying to change the background color of a QTableWidget row. There are some others posts about the same thing but none of the given solutions worked for me.

- With that solution, we are setting the background on an already existing item in the table to a light grey on the item at row 0, column 1:

  `self.table.item(1,0).setBackground(QtGui.QColor(125,125,125))`

It's working, but set background for the row with iterating needs more time if you have more then one table. **I need a function to change the row background by passing only the row index!**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no function that performs this task, but we can create it, for example:

```
def setColortoRow(table, rowIndex, color):
    for j in range(table.columnCount()):
        table.item(rowIndex, j).setBackground(color)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a function that can set the background color of the tableWidget to a specific color? I mean for example all cells have gray background regardless of having or not having a value.

Comment: What is example of `color`?  It requires `PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem.setBackground(PySide2.QtGui.QBrush)`?

Comment: use `item.setBackground(QBrush(color))`